# How to pass argument from a dynamically created button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm writing a userscript using tampermonkey with a goal of adding a button to forum message board that when pressed will make the post where the button was pressed disappear.

For instance, you have a few posts: post1, post2, post3. You press on the button of post 1 and then you only have post2 and post3.

I managed to add the button but I can't figure out how I tie the `onclick` event of that button to the specific `<div>` I want it to hide. My logic says that I need to pass an argument to the button that will tell the function that's tied to it what '' I want gone. But I can't understand how to pass an argument to that function.

I have the following DOM structure:

```html
<div id="post1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some text1</td>
            <td>some more text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="post2">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some text2</td>
            <td>some more text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="post3">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some text3</td>
            <td>some more text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="post4">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>some text4</td>
            <td>some more text</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My user script is adding another column to the table with a button when the button I mentioned above. This is the function I want to execute when the button is clicked:

```js
function hidePost(postId){
    jQuery('#'+postId).hide();
}
```

This is how I'm adding the columns and the buttons:

```js
function addColumn(){
    jQuery("div").each(function (index){
        let currentPostId = (jQuery(this).attr("id"));        

        let columnRow = document.createElement('td');                
        let clearButton = document.createElement('button')

        clearButton.text = "Clear Button";
        clearButton.onclick = hidePost(currentPostId) //Here is my problem. I don't know how to pass an argument to onclick method.

        
        columnRow.appendChild(clearButton);   
    
        jQuery(this).find("tr").each(function(){            
            jQuery(this).find('td').eq(1).after(columnRow.outerHTML)
        })
    });
}
```

Only this doesn't work. When I try to pass the argument to `onclick` in this way it just executes the function on assignment. I tried different approaches like passing a string `clearButton.onclick ='hidePost(\"+postId+\");'` I also tried to register a call back using jquery like so:

```js
let clearButton = document.createElement('button')
jQuery(clearButton).click(function(){
    jQuery('#'+postId).hide();
})
```

But this didn't work either.

I should point out that I'm doing this in a Tampermonkey script. So maybe the issue is there. Also, I think it's prudent to say that I'm very new to javascript and jquery and user scripts in general. So I'm quite sure there are multiple things that I'm doing in this example that are wrong. If you have a better approach to achieve what I'm trying to achieve, I'm all ears.

Comment: `$( "body" ).on( "click", ".taper-btn", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});` https://api.jquery.com/on/; Use "on" method in jquery to trigger events on dynamically added elements

Comment: My guess is that `.after(colomnRow.outerHTML)` loses its attached events... As already said: A working example would help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issues in your logic is that you're invoking `hidePost()` immediately and assigning its return value, which is undefined, as the event handler for the button. Instead you need to wrap it in an anonymous function so that it's only executed *after* the button is clicked:

```
clearButton.onclick = function() { hidePost(currentPostId); }
```

In addition there is no `text` property of an Element object. That should be `textContent` instead.

However it's worth noting that your logic is *a lot* more complicated that it needs to be. If you use a single delegated event handler for all the `button` elements then all you need to do is traverse the DOM to find the closest parent `tr` and hide it. There's no need to involve the `id` of the elements at all. Try this:

```js
(function($) {
  $('div').on('click', '.clear', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
  });

  $("div tr").append('<td><button class="clear">Clear</button></td>');
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post1">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>some text1</td>
      <td>some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="post2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>some text2</td>
      <td>some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="post3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>some text3</td>
      <td>some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="post4">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>some text4</td>
      <td>some more text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note the use of the IIFE to create a local scope for you to use the `$` variable to reference jQuery as normal without interfering with the code in the rest of the page.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Sadly using the anonymous function like so `clearButton.onclick = function() { hidePost(currentPostId); }` didn't work. Though your other solution seems to be better but I don't quite understand where do I need to put the function you suggest. Who calls it and when does it run?

Comment: It goes in the TamperMonkey script you said you were creating. It runs on load of the page.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a combination of yours and @Prikesh Savla answers. I registered a callback to the `onClick` event in the 'body' part of the document `jQuery("body").on("click",".checked-button", function(){}` Then inside the function I used `this` to seek the closest `div` like you said, like so `jQuery(this).closest("div[id^=post]").hide()`. I apologize if this is exactly the same thing you were saying all along. I just got a bit confused by the syntax of your function.